# Keys not working in chromedriver headless

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys, headless

I want to send text to Google search engine but copy and paste method exclusively
When I work on Google Chrome with windows there is no problem
But when used **chromedriver** **headless**, do not paste the copies into the search box
This is the code in Python

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
browserP webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path=path)
browserP.get("https://www.google.com/")
**browserP.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL , "v")**
time.sleep(2)
browserP.get_screenshot_as_file("capture.png")
```